# flutter fetch data textformfield

Tags: flutter, api, dart, full-text-search

This is my search code when i search and show listview how can i want the textformfield outside listview to fetch after complete search?

I typed some text into the search box and the data was fetched successfully. But I want the textfield outside the listview to have text after search, what should I do? i am practicing

```
onSearch(String text) async {
if (text.isNotEmpty) {
  List<Item> itemList = [];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (item.custnum == text.toString().toLowerCase().toUpperCase()) {
      itemList.add(item);
      setState(() {
        searchitems.clear();
        searchitems.addAll(itemList);
        print('name : ${searchitems[0].name}');
        if (searchitems.isEmpty) {
          searchitems = [];
          // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!.length}');
          // print('searchitems : ${searchitems[0].address!}');
        }
      });
    }
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    searchitems.clear();
    // searchitems.addAll(items);
    print('searchitems : $searchitems');
  });
}
```

This is TextFormField

```
                TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'supermarket', fontSize: 14),
                            isDense: true,
                          ),
                        ),
```

This is listview

```
child: searchitems.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      controller: controllerlistview,
                      itemCount: searchitems[0].address!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: ((context) => EditAddressPage(
                                        custaddr:
                                            searchitems[0].address![0]))));
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        'แก้ไข${searchitems[0].name}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: "supermarket",
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'bill To / Ship To : ${searchitems[0].address![index].shipto.toString()}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontFamily: "supermarket"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "ที่อยู่ : ${searchitems[0].address![index].addr1.toString()}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontFamily: "supermarket"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      })
                  : Center(child: Text('ไม่มีข้อมูล'))),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just assign this to your TextFormField and you can get the search box value from it.

        final textController=TextEditingController();

         TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'name',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'supermarket', fontSize: 14),
          isDense: true,
        ),
        controller: textController,
      ),
```